# GCE allow incoming traffic on specific ports

Tags: c#, google-compute-engine, firewall, .net-core

I'm trying to host a TCP socket server on a Google Compute Engine, i added the following rule on GCE firewall-rules (sockets-port   0.0.0.0/0   tcp:11000   Apply to all targets) but the port is still inaccessible from the outside using the public IP (ephemeral in my case).

Is there more to be done in this case? should i use ufw on the VM itself to set additional rules?

Any help or hints would be appreciated, thx.

EDIT: 
1) firewall settings:

NAME                    NETWORK  SRC_RANGES    RULES                         SRC_TAGS  TARGET_TAGS

default-allow-http      default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:80                                  http-server

default-allow-https     default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:443                                 https-server

default-allow-icmp      default  0.0.0.0/0     icmp

default-allow-internal  default  10.128.0.0/9  tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp

default-allow-rdp       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:3389

default-allow-ssh       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:22

sockets-port            default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:11000

2) on the VM itself the SocketListener class (C#) gives the error :

> Cannot assign requested address
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)

"IPEndpoint consists of the public IP of the machine and port 11000

Comment: 1) Paste your firewall settings here; 2) What error code you get? 3) Try to access it from another VM in the same network via internal IP, to make sure the service is up.

Comment: @Dagang Edited my question, but at the moment i cant access from another vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem with GCE, you must bind your server socket to 0.0.0.0, instead of the external IP. I don't know if this is by design.

The external IP is a virtual IP. The infrastructure knows how to direct traffic targeting the IP to your VM,  but it is not bound to any of the VM's network interfaces. If you run `sudo ifconfig` in the VM, you will only see the internal IP on eth0.